# mediaDevices.getUserMedia image cropped / zoomed in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webcam, getusermedia

Getting the camera stream with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(` shows a picture that appears to crop the edges out in the browser. The full image can be seen through the native camera application. The same appears to happen with both my Huawei Honor 8 and my laptop, both in Chrome. Microsoft Edge on the laptop however showed the image correctly.

I have tried different aspect ratios with the constraints. 4:3 aspect ratio appears to perform only slightly better than 16:9. These features are known to be fiddly but this problem causes significant problems for my application. Especially on the phone, the image quality is significantly worse.

Any help with the issue is appreciated although I don't know if this can be fixed.

[image: Picture illustrating the issue]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
function hasGetUserMedia() {
  return !!(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}
if(hasGetUserMedia()){
  const video = document.getElementById('camera');
  const device_ids = [];
  var device = -1;

  function success(stream){
    video.srcObject = stream;
  }

  function error(error){
    alert("Something went wrong :( It could be this app is not supported by your browser\n" + error);
  }

  var constraints = {
    video: {
      facingMode: "environment",
      aspectRatio: 1.7777777778
    }
  };
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(success).catch(error);
}else{
  alert("This application is not supported on your browser :(");
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="camera" autoplay></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a layout problem. [Check the stream dimensions](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/3hksbngx/) rather than relying on visual inspection to isolate your problem.

Comment: Same issue here... Everything is OK on Samsung Galaxy but on Motorola Moto X it seems that the video stream crops the image. When takePhoto() is invoked the result is a photo showing things that didn't appear in video preview.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue, and for me this solved it:

```
var constraints = {
  video: {
    facingMode: "environment",
    aspectRatio: { exact: 1.7777777778 }
  }
};
```

You can play in the same fiddle that @jib posted in the comment and see that if you don't force the aspect ratio with `exact` it doesn't really do anything, but the moment you use it, it changes the video size.